# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar productos según su categoria/categoría_id?

Tags: php, html, mysql

estuve siguiendo un tutorial de carrito de compras y es muy completo y está bastante bien, no se mucho de PHP pero me pude arreglar para hacer bastantes cosas, pero esta si que no se me ocurre nada de como hacerla. Quiero mostrar productos según la categoría, porque, no logro mostrar algunos de los porductos de la base de datos sino que el código imprime todos los productos que hay en ella. Por eso, se me ocurrió filtrarlos por categoría, y he aquí el problema.

Archivo Producto.php, aquí está la lógica de insertar,actualizar,eliminar y mostrar los productos.

```
    
namespace Akron;
    
    class Producto{
        
        private $config;
        private $cn = null;
        
        public function __construct(){
            $this->config = parse_ini_file(__DIR__.'/../config.ini');
            
            $this->cn = new \PDO($this->config['dns'], $this->config['usuario'], $this->config['clave'], array(
            
                    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>'SET NAMES utf8'
            ));
            
            
            
        }
        
        
        public function registrar ($_params){
            
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `productos`(`titulo`, `descripcion`, `foto`, `precio`, `precio_anterior`, `categoria_id`) 
            VALUES (:titulo,:descripcion,:foto,:precio,:precio_anterior,:categoria_id)";
            
            $resultado = $this->cn->prepare($sql);
            
            $_array = array(
                
                ":titulo" =>$_params['titulo'],
                ":descripcion" =>$_params['descripcion'],
                ":foto" =>$_params['foto'],
                ":precio" =>$_params['precio'],
                ":precio_anterior" =>$_params['precio_anterior'],
                ":categoria_id" =>$_params['categoria_id'],
                
            );
            
            if($resultado->execute($_array))
                
                return true;
                
                return false;
        }
        
    public function actualizar($_params){
        $sql = "UPDATE `productos` SET `titulo`=:titulo,`descripcion`=:descripcion,`foto`=:foto,`precio`=:precio,`precio_anterior`=:precio_anterior, `categoria_id`=:categoria_id WHERE `id`=:id";

        $resultado = $this->cn->prepare($sql);

        $_array = array(
            ":titulo" => $_params['titulo'],
            ":descripcion" => $_params['descripcion'],
            ":foto" => $_params['foto'],
            ":precio" => $_params['precio'],
            ":precio_anterior" => $_params['precio_anterior'],
            ":categoria_id" => $_params['categoria_id'],
            ":id" =>  $_params['id']
        );

        if($resultado->execute($_array))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
        
        
        
        
    public function eliminar($id){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM `productos` WHERE `id`=:id";

        $resultado = $this->cn->prepare($sql);
        
        $_array = array(
            ":id" =>  $id
        );

        if($resultado->execute($_array))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
        
        public function mostrar (){
            
            $sql = "SELECT productos.id, titulo, descripcion, foto, nombre, precio, precio_anterior, estado FROM `productos`
            
            INNER JOIN categorias
            ON productos.categoria_id = categorias.id ORDER BY productos.id DESC
            ";
            
            $resultado = $this->cn->prepare($sql);
            
            
            if($resultado->execute())
                
                return $resultado->fetchAll();
                
                return false;
            
            
        }
        
            public function mostrarPorId($id){
        
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `id`=:id ";
        
                    $resultado = $this->cn->prepare($sql);
                    $_array = array(
                        ":id" =>  $id
                    );

                    if($resultado->execute($_array))
                        return $resultado->fetch();

                    return false;
            }
                    
        
    }
?>
```

Aquí, Categoría.php, que se encarga de registrar los productos según la categoría que elegí

```
<?php

namespace Akron;

class Categoria{
    
    
    private $config;
    private $cn = null;
    
    public function __construct(){
        $this->config = parse_ini_file(__DIR__.'/../config.ini');
        
        $this->cn = new \PDO($this->config['dns'], $this->config['usuario'], $this->config['clave'], array(
        
                \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>'SET NAMES utf8'
        ));
        
        
        
    }
    
    public function mostrar (){
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM categorias";
        
        $resultado = $this->cn->prepare($sql);
        
        
        if($resultado->execute())
            
            return $resultado->fetchAll();
            
            return false;
        
        
    }
    
}
```

He aquí donde entran ustedes. Si olvide agregar algo por favor me notifican, algunos datos más:
La tabla se llama "categorias"
Cada categoría esta identificada con su respectiva "categoria_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tan solo he copiado tu código de la función `mostrar` y lo he modificado un poco:

```
public function mostrarDeCategoria($catId){//Recibimos la ID de la categoría que quieres mostrar
        
    //Exactamente el mismo select que el de mostrar, pero con el where para filtrar por categoría
    $sql = "SELECT productos.id, titulo, descripcion, foto, nombre, precio, precio_anterior, estado FROM `productos` 
    INNER JOIN categorias 
    ON productos.categoria_id = categorias.id 
    WHERE categorias.id = :catId 
    ORDER BY productos.id DESC
    ";
    
    $resultado = $this->cn->prepare($sql);
    //He copiado y modificado el _array de tu código para que sea lo más parecido posible
    $_array = array(
        ":catId" =>  $catId
    );
    
    if($resultado->execute($_array))
        return $resultado->fetchAll();
    return false;
}
```

En los comentarios te dejo las explicaciones de lo que hice.

Comment: Muchas gracias. ¿Esto debería ir en el index? ¿Cómo muestro por ejemplo la categoría con value 1? De nuevo te digo muchas gracias por tu tiempo, muy amable.

Comment: Si te sirve la respuesta no olvides marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Si, pero antes podrías responderme las preguntas que te realicé en el comentario, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Eso es una función más de tu clase Producto, y los muestras igual que cuando llamas al método mostrar(), pero pasándole la id de la categoría que quieres mostrar, si es la 1 pues llamas al método `mostrarDeCategoria(1);` y ya te devolverá solo los productos que pertenezcan a esa categoría

Comment: Eres un genio!!!1 Mil gracias